# If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continous at $s$, then if $s<b$ can I find an $x \in [a,b]$ with $s<x<s+\delta$?

Tags: continuity, epsilon-delta

> If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continous at $s$ where $s \in [a,b)$, then if $s<b$ can I find an $x \in [a,b]$ with $s<x<s+\delta$?

$\delta$ is $\delta$ of the epsilon-delta definition of continuity. I was able to prove it graphically but is there a way to show it analytically?

Comment: $f$ isn't mentioned in the conclusion. Yes there is a continuous $f\colon [a,b]\to \Bbb R$, so the statement is equivalent to: "if $s<b$ then there is $x\in [a,b]$ with $s<x<x+\delta$". Please fix.

Comment: Furthermore, if $s<a$ and $\delta < a-s$ then $x<a$ if it satisfies the inequalities so there is no such $x$; you should require something about $s$. Also, $a<b$ would help.

Comment: @BrianO Thanks for answering, s $\in$ [a,b) where a<b  and I focus on the case $s<b$

Comment: You should state $s\in [a,b)$ in the question, which also pleasantly implies that $a<b$. $f$ is irrelevant, get rid of it.

Comment: Please edit the question to get rid of all mention of $f$.

Comment: Why is $f$ irrelevant? I use the fact that $f$ is continous at $s$ to explain for example the use of $\delta$. I used the delta epsilon definition of continuity of $f$ at $s$ to show the statement graphically as well.

Comment: It's not mentioned anywhere in the conclusion of the main statement, whose truth and proof have nothing to do with any function from anything to anything.

Answer (score 2):

You've added in a comment that $a\le s<b$.
Without loss of generality you can assume that $\delta \le b-s$. Simply take $x = s + \frac {\delta} 2$.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Should I also contemplate the case for s<b<=$\delta$+s. Not sure if this is possible

Comment: No. Why bother? If you can prove it for $\delta < b-s$ then the result also holds for larger $\delta' \ge \delta$. **However**, you *should* mention that that is why it's enough to prove it for $\delta < b-s$ "without loss of generality".

Comment: if I can prove it for $\delta<b-s$ is the same as $\delta+s<b$ ie $b$ is greater than $\delta+s$. That's why I asked for the case where $s<b<=\delta+s$

Comment: Um, please reread my previous comment.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to understand it but I can't, Could you please give me another hint?

Comment: I don't even understand what you don't understand. Suppose you have some $\delta'$ and you want to prove that there is $x\in [a,b]$ such that $s < x < x+\delta'$. Let $\delta = \min(\delta', b-s)$. Then the proof shows that $s < x < x+\delta$; but $\delta\le\delta'$, so $x <x+\delta'$ too.